# Nodejs join users to custom rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js

You suppose i have 3 room such as room1, room2 and room3

i want to join some users to this rooms, how can i do that?

my code doesn't correct and i can't do that

```
var socket      = require('socket.io'),
    express     = require('express'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    app         = express(),
    server      = require('http').createServer(app),
    io          = socket.listen(server),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    redis       = require("redis"),
    redisClient = redis.createClient(),
    forever     = require('forever'),
    log         = require('log4node');

var io_redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(io_redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));

require('sticky-socket-cluster/replace-console')();

var options = {
    workers     : require('os').cpus().length,
    first_port  : 8000,
    proxy_port  : 3000,
    session_hash: function (req, res) {
        return req.connection.remoteAddress;
    },

    no_sockets: false
};
var room    = ["room1","room2","room3"];
require('sticky-socket-cluster')(options, start);

function start(port) {
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('room1', function (room) {
            socket.join(room[0])
        });

        socket.on('room2', function (room) {
            socket.join(room[1])
        });    
    });
    server.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Express and socket.io listening on port ' + port);
    });
}
```

when i use this code to join users as :

```
socket.on('room1', function (room) {
    socket.join(room[0])
});
```

i get no result and code doesn't work and i don't know how can i do that

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @NewbeeDev i updated post sir, i dont get any result after join to room and get message

Comment: did you pass properly a json data in your "room1" emit in client side?

Comment: could you provide also your emit in client side?

Comment: @NewbeeDev for joining user i dont pass any json data to socket, i only connected to server and i 'm calling `room1` from client, client is android application and it is `application.getSocket().emit("room1");`

Comment: you must passed a parameter json in your emit application.getSocket().emit("room1",'roomno')

Comment: @NewbeeDev i can create empty room and join users into that, but i can't join users to created rooms as i said on post

Comment: @NewbeeDev thanks, but whats `roomno`? its username?

Comment: maybe a chathash? try passing a roomno instead of leaving it blank

Comment: @NewbeeDev `chathash` ? i dont know whats that, could you explain about that?

Comment: just a term I call for room name

Comment: what's your goal anyway to send a data to all users join your room?

Comment: @NewbeeDev i edited client to pass argument to socket, but it didn't any change, and i send message to room users by this code: `socket.on('roomMessage', function (room) {
    io.sockets.in(room).emit('roomMessage', {message: 'Hi!! '});
});` its only work when i use empty rooms, not default rooms

Comment: try using static value for room